# set previous month/year as macro variable in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I know something like this

```
%let start_date = %sysfunc(intnx(day,%sysfunc(date()),-1),DATE9.);
%put &start_date;
```

But

```
%let start_month = %sysfunc(month(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1),DATE9.));
%put &start_month;
```

or

```
%let start_date = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1),DATE9.);
%put %sysfunc(month(&start_date));
```

doesn't work.

Comment: could you check if individual part of your let statement working? like check if intnx returning what it should?

Comment: %let start_month = %sysfunc(month(%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1))));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another %SYSFUNC before INTNX for your example to work.

```
%let start_month = %sysfunc(month(%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1))));
%put &start_month;
```

However, I prefer to use DATA NULL where a lot of %SYSFUNC statements are required with %LET.  The following gives you the same result.

```
data _null_;
call symputx('start_month ', month(intnx('month',date(),-1)));
run;
%put &start_month.;
```